# Interpolate a correction vector for xts object in R. Subtract background level from values

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have many xts objects with structure:

```html
*                    Resp_1      
... 
2014-11-24 18:45:41 " 4.98683210"
2014-11-24 18:45:52 " 4.94921172"
2014-11-24 18:46:02 " 4.95605396"
2014-11-24 18:46:12 " 4.95352998"
2014-11-24 18:46:23 " 4.99771640"
2014-11-24 18:46:33 " 4.98459552"
2014-11-24 18:46:44 " 5.00530512"
2014-11-24 18:46:54 " 4.98655576"
2014-11-24 18:47:04 " 4.98136715"
2014-11-24 18:47:15 " 5.01771098"
...
```

where measured values have timestamps.

Due to the way the experiment was conducted, the values of interest contain a background level that needs to be subtracted. What makes this more difficult is that the background level is not constant and using a single correction value is not possible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw67A.jpg

So the background level was measured before and after the experiment (seen on picture at the ends of the dashed red line).

Now I want to subtract the background level from measured values. The way I thought to do this is to create a interpolated background level vector between the before and after background levels and then simply subtract this vector from the Resp_1 values.

Currently I have managed to manually determine from graphs the time periods that contain the before and after background levels and compute averages of both.
For example:

```html
backg_before<-mean(as.numeric(df$Resp_1["2014-11-24 18:45:40/2014-11-24 18:47:20"]))
backg_after<-mean(as.numeric(df$Resp_1["2014-11-25 09:33:00/2014-11-25 09:36:00"]))
```

So I know the average before and after background level but I do not know how to interpolate a vector between the two levels.

The vector should go through the middles of the selected before and after time periods. For example the average before background level is 4.98 and the timeline location for it should be about 18:46:28. Since no such time-stamp exists it could also be the closest existing time-stamp (18:46:23 or 18:46:33).

I do not know how to find the middle of a xts time series index. Is there a way to do it?

And how to build the required vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be solved by adding a UNIX time-stamp format from existing xts index. Then it is easy to calculate the middles of time series as the means of second counts.

UNIX seconds also make building the vector easy, as simple algebra can be used to find the needed slope and y-intercept.